# Import/Export Version History Modified Date

Tags: stsadm, import

Im migrating a SPS2003 site to MOSS 2007. Its crucial I maintain version history. I followed this process:

1. Do the pre upgrade check
2. Backup DB from SPS2003
3. Restore DB to SQL in virtual machine with MOSS 2007
4. Attach DB to empty site in MOSS 2007 in my virtual machine

At this point i have the 2003 content in 2007 with the correct meta date (username, modified date etc). I now need to move the site from my virtual machine to our stage then live environments.

1. Export the site using stsadm (with -includeusersecurity and -versions 4)
2. Import the site into staging environment using stsadm (with -includesecurity).

This all works ok and I have the site, complete with metadata. However the modified date of the version history is changing to the last modified datetime of the document for each version. The user who created each version is intact.

Ive read some contradicting info on the old net, but is it possible to maintain the version history modified date?

Im running MOSS 2007 SP2 on my virtual machine and staging environment

Comment: This is a very old question, but it seems to be an issue in 2010 as well. I moved a content DB from 2003 to 2007 to 2010 using backup/restore. The version history date is correct in 2007 and 2010. As soon as I do a Import-SPWeb/Export-SPWeb (on a single doc library) from 2010 to another 2010 site in the same farm, the version history date is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use stsadm and detach the database from your vm and then attach it on your other environments?
you can use stsadm -o deletecontentdb (despite the name this actually detaches the db without deleting it) 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262449(office.12).aspx
then you can copy the this db and attach it on your other environments.

Hope this helps

Renzo

Comment: The site collection in SPS2003 only has this one site, so attaching it to the VM is ok as its my dev environment. I actually want to take the site and add it to an existing site collection in my other environments. As far as im aware doing what you suggest would give me a whole new site collection.

Comment: Yes this solution doesn't work for adding to existing site collection sorry